# Sum Values Based on a Category and a Month (Date)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am in need of adding up any values in column E that coorespond to a particular month and category.  E.g. Any amounts in January (from Column D) that are categorized as Income in Column A.

Here is an example of my data.  Needing help with what formula will return the sum I'm looking for here.

Sample data[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9bYh.png)

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: (1) Please post textual data as text, not as an image.  (2) You’re more likely to get help if you give an example expected result for your example input data.  (I guess you want $700?)  (3) If you need to match substrings (matching “Main Income” and “Side Income” when you’re looking for “Income”), you need to say so.  (4) Look at  `SUMIFS`.

Comment: @amdavis714  ,,,, others than SUMPRODUCT the `SUMIFS` can be used also !

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether following formula is helpful.

`=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(D2:D4)=1)*(A2:A4="Income")*(E2:E4))`

[image]

Comment: ,,, easy & better one ,,,, +10 ☺